# What's the basis costant $K_b$ of $(ne_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the standard basis of $\ell^2$ with basis constant $K_b=1$

We know that also $(ne_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Schauder basis of $\ell^2$

My question is: what's the basis constant $K_b$ of $(ne_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of 'basis constant' ?

Comment: @daw It's the sup of the partial sum projections associated to a basis, the concept concerns the Schauder basis (Topics In Banach Space Theory - Albiac, Kalton, page 5)

Comment: I believe the answer comes directly from the definition. So please state it. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644945/the-importance-of-basis-constant , which basically tells you that $K=1$ for $(ne_n)$.

Comment: Ok @daw thanks for your answer